# Java Bubble sorting not working

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

I just want to write a program that sorts 3 integers. The integers are entered from the input dialog. My code is really simple. I just need to get some data and put them in array called `num`. and then I create a method to sort the data by using bubble-sort logic. that method called `sort`. I have added command to display the sorted result with `System.out.println("Sorted Result : "+Arrays.toString(num))` but that's not working.
The output just let me input data and then nothing happen.

Can anyone please tell me something I miss or what I did wrong?
Thank you.

```
package numThree;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class sort {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int[] num = new int[3];


            //INPUT DATA
            System.out.println("Enter integers : ");

            for(int i=0;i<=num.length;i++){

                num[i]=sc.nextInt();

            }

            sort(num);

    }

    //SORTING
    public static void sort (int[] num){

        for(int i=0;i<=num.length-1;i++){

            for(int j=0;j<=num.length-i;j++){

                if(num[j-1]>num[j]){
                    int temp = num[j];
                    num[j] = num[j-1];
                    num[j-1] = temp;
                }

            }


            System.out.println("Sorted Result : "+Arrays.toString(num));

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Move the println to below the closing brace for the outer for-loop.

Comment: Code looks ok, You need put the print in the bottom of main function    ->  System.out.println("Sorted Result : "+Arrays.toString(num));

Comment: Bubble sort isn't implemented with for loops.

Comment: @Natecat ...what? Of course it is. Sure, you could use while loops too if you wanted, but for loops are the typical implementation, in my experience. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Implementation).

Comment: @NathanHughes still not working... anyway, do you think the problem in this line? `public static void sort (int[] num)`

Comment: @Mage Xy yes you use a inner for loop to loop through the array, but you use an outer while loop that keeps looping until the array is sorted

Comment: it never gets as far as the sort, it fails on the data entry part, the loop index test is wrong: in `i<=num.length`,  the `<=` should be `<`

Comment: @Natecat You are correct, that would be the optimal way to implement it. A fully naive approach would use two for loops and iterate though the entire array n^2 times, even if the array is sorted a few iterations early.

Comment: @Natecat: wasn't talking about within the sort method.

Comment: Do you guys think that my problem would be in this line: `public static void sort (int[] num)` ? becase I see that I have 2 main functions. But if I'm right, is there any suggestion to correct this?

Comment: @NathanHughes Thank you. But I think it just solved problem for the data entry bug because array start from 0. But I'm still struggling for this main problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need a boolean flag to implement a bubble sort as you cannot know in advance how many times the loop will perform the swapping of consecutive elements.

Try this:

```
package numThree;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class sort {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] num = new int[3];


        //INPUT DATA
        System.out.println("Enter integers : ");

        for(int i=0;i<=num.length;i++){

            num[i]=sc.nextInt();

        }

        sort(num);

    }

    //SORTING
    public static void sort (int[] num){
       boolean swapped = true;
       while(swapped){ 
           swapped = false;
           for(int i=0;i<num.length-1;i++){

                if(num[i]>num[i+1]){
                    int temp = num[i];
                    num[i] = num[i+1];
                    num[i+1] = temp;
                    swapped = true;
                }
           }
       }
       System.out.println("Sorted Result : "+Arrays.toString(num));
    }
}
```

Note that it can still be slightly improved: each time around the loop the largest number will end up as far as it can get towards the end of of the array: there's no need to check or swap till the end each time. 
By using a variable as the upper limit of the index `i` and decreasing its value after the for loop you can reduce the total number of iterations.

```
int end = num.length-1;
while(swapped){ 
   swapped = false;
   for(int i=0;i<end;i++){

        if(num[i]>num[i+1]){
            int temp = num[i];
            num[i] = num[i+1];
            num[i+1] = temp;
            swapped = true;
        }
    }
    end--;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you! that's awesome! this code will work by correcting entry data part in `for(int i=0;i<=num.length;i++)` to `i<num.length`. Thanks to @NathanHughes too.